# setup dependent triggers google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a trigger which copies data to a google sheet and does some data crunching and manipulates data for business user reporting. I then have another trigger which copies this data to another spreadsheet for which the users have access to. Is there a way to create a dependency on the trigger when trigger A is successful run trigger B?

Comment: Both triggers are in the same project? and what type of triggers are they?

Answer (score 0):

triggers dont support dependencies or workflows. however, you can create the one-time trigger once your first one finishes. you can also just call the 2nd function directly if you think both will run before the six minute limit runs out.

when creating the trigger, over time those accumulate in the triggers list. you can have another trigger to delete those regularly, or have the trigger remove itself..